# On listing or in listing?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

I know that when it comes to graphical elements (such as figures, pictures, photos) you should always use ***in***, for instance:

1. ***in*** the picture,
2. ***in*** figure 4,
3. ...

But what about code listing? Should I write "on listing 3" or "in listing 3"?

I would like to say something like this:

> As it can be seen **on/in** listing 3, the variable needs to be initialized with the value of 1024.

I meant the source code listing. The code of the computer program, given in text.

On/in listing below, the `port` variable is initialized with the value of `1024`:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char * ip_addr;
    int port = 1024;

    // ... 
}
```

Comment: What is "code listing" / "listing 3"? More detail is needed.

Comment: Do you mean "*line* 3" instead of "listing 3"?

Comment: Is "listing" a self-contained set of lines of code, such as an example function?

Answer (score 1):

**In** the listing is what this native US English speaker would say, and [Google Ngrams shows *in* to be much more common.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20listing%2Con%20listing%2Cin%20the%20listing%2Con%20the%20listing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20listing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20listing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20the%20listing%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20the%20listing%3B%2Cc0)

In general, we use *in* for anything printed, and anything that something else could literally be inside of:

> Have you seen the article in today's newspaper?
>   As it says in the Bible...
>   The details are in the latest report.

*On* is used more with means of broadcast communication:

> I saw it on the internet.
>   The president will be on TV today.

But there are some exceptions.  We say something is **on a page**, like

> You will find the recipe on page five.
>   perhaps because the information is literally printed on top of the page.  And we also say that something is **on the menu**, maybe because *menu* doesn't necessarily refer just to the literal printed menu.